# Unity. Just one scene in GearVR

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gear-vr

i'm trying to create an android app what starts as simple app after changes to a scene in GearVR.

I'm working in Unity 5.6.
I tried to activate/disable VR support from code, but it doesn't switch in runtime.

So, is there a method to do this?

Thx.

Comment: Please the code that's not working

Answer (score 0):

> This is not available in GearVR at the moment but Oculus has a plan to
>   support dual-mode (VR and Non-VR) in future.

Follow [this thread](https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/44114/how-to-switch-between-vr-and-non-vr-mode-as-in-the-samsung-gear-360-app-with-unity-android) for updates.

However, switching between VR and Non-VR mode is [possible](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/wiki/Switching-between-VR-and-non-VR-at-runtime) in Google VR.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thx for answer.